# Iterate through adjacent pairs of items in a Python list

Tags: python, list, loops

Is it possible to iterate a list in the following way in Python (treat this code as pseudocode)?

```
a = [5, 7, 11, 4, 5]
for v, w in a:
    print [v, w]
```

And it should produce

```
[5, 7]
[7, 11]
[11, 4]
[4, 5]
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

From the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for v, w in pairwise(a):
    ...
```

Comment: Nice, but is not this overkilling?. What is the advantage of your approach relative to the simple for-loop in the answer from SanSS? I timed both and the speed was very similar (itertools wins by ca 10%, no big deal)

Comment: @joaquin: The difference is that it works on iterators, not just sequences. That's not needed here, but you can hardly call that overkill. I just prefer iterators because I work with them all the time.

Comment: For anyone interested in circular pairs from e.g. a list `a`, just do: `pairwise(a +[a[0] ] )`.

Comment: Note to those finding this, the advantage that this works on iterators is that this does not require random access into a stream of data (i.e. array access); rather, it only needs to ingest each item once, and caches it for the next evaluation. So if you have, say, a Twitter firehose, you don't ever need to read the firehose into a gigantic (perhaps infinite-length) array for this to work.

Comment: This solution does not drop last element if iterable cardinality is odd VS zip.

Comment: In Python 3, you will get `ImportError: cannot import name 'izip' from 'itertools' (unknown location)`. You can just use `zip` instead of `izip` from itertools in Python 3.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis In python3 where only `zip_longest` exists in itertools, I got it working like this: `zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=iterable[0])`. Else, I would get an additional tupel of `(a[0], None)` as the last output if I used `pairwise(a +[a[0] ] )`
I did not test if my approach works for any type of iterable though, my input is a list and it works for lists.

Comment: The last tuple in `list(pairwise(a + [a[0]])` is `(a[-1], a[0])`.

Comment: In Python 3.10, you can use `itertools.pairwise`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise

Answer (score 222):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) the list with itself sans the first element:

```
a = [5, 7, 11, 4, 5]

for previous, current in zip(a, a[1:]):
    print(previous, current)
```

This works even if your list has no elements or only 1 element (in which case `zip` returns an empty iterable and the code in the `for` loop never executes). It doesn't work on [generators](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types), only [sequences](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) (`tuple`, `list`, `str`, etc).

Comment: This does not work. Each of the separate lists you are iterating do not sufficiently "skip" the next record, so your example gives output like:[5, 7]
[7, 11]
[11, 4]
[4, 5]

Comment: But that's exactly the result we want, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm...yea - I think the OP was looking for it - though I saw "pairwise" iteration as returning like [5,7], [11,4], [5,None]

Comment: @Brad For this case, `zip(a[::2], a[1::2])`, which will step by 2 through each list.

Answer (score 63):

To do that you should do:

```
a =  [5, 7, 11, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    print [a[i], a[i+1]]
```

Comment: Referencing a list item by index is something of an anti-pattern in Python (except when the items must be access out-of-sequence). See https://github.com/JeffPaine/beautiful_idiomatic_python#looping-over-a-collection

Answer (score 18):

Nearly verbatim from [Iterate over pairs in a list (circular fashion) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257413/iterate-over-pairs-in-a-list-circular-fashion-in-python/1257446#1257446):

```
def pairs(seq):
    i = iter(seq)
    prev = next(i)
    for item in i:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
```

Comment: An empty list will raise `StopIteration` at `i.next()`.

Comment: Tested this works in Py2.x and 3.x now.

Comment: To fix empty list wrap 3rd line in `try:` `except StopIteration: return`

Answer (score 11):

An alternative way is [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (Python 3.10 or later):

```
from itertools import pairwise

temp = [-39.5, -27.5, -15.5, -3.5, 8.5, 20.5, 32.5, 44.5, 56.5, 68.5, 80.5, 92.5,104.5]
res = list(pairwise(temp))
```

---

```
[(-39.5, -27.5), (-27.5, -15.5), (-15.5, -3.5), (-3.5, 8.5), (8.5, 20.5), (20.5, 32.5), (32.5, 44.5), (44.5, 56.5), (56.5, 68.5), (68.5, 80.5), (80.5, 92.5), (92.5, 104.5)]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = [5, 7, 11, 4, 5]
>>> for n,k in enumerate(a[:-1]):
...     print a[n],a[n+1]
...
5 7
7 11
11 4
4 5
```

Comment: why `enumerate` if you're not going to use `k`?

Comment: I guess because we need the index.

Comment: @Tanin Then wouldn't `for n i range(len(a)):` be more accurate and idiomatic?

Comment: Yes, range(len(a) - 1) is better.