# Defaultdict(defaultdict) for text analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, defaultdict

Text read from file and cleaned up:

```
['the', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog', 'fled']
```

The challenge is to return a dict with each word as the value and the words that can follow it as the key and a count for the number of times it follows it:

```
{'the': {'cat': 1, 'dog': 1}, 'chased': {'the': 1}, 'cat': {'chased': 1}, 'dog': {'fled': 1}}
```

Collections.counter will count the frequency of each unique value.  However, my algorithm to solve this challenge is long and unwieldy.  How might **defaultdict** be used to make solving this more simple?

EDIT:  here is my code to bruise through this problem.  A flaw is that the values in the nested dict are the total number of times a word appears in the text, not how many times it actually follows that particular word.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

wordsFile = f.read()
words = [x.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for x in wordsFile.split()]    
counter = Counter(words)

# the dict of [unique word]:[index of appearance in 'words']
index = defaultdict(list) 

# Appends every position of 'term' to the 'term' key
for pos, term in enumerate(words):
    index[term].append(pos)  

# range ends at len(index) - 2 because last word in text has no follower
master = {}
for i in range(0,(len(index)-2)):

    # z will hold the [index of appearance in 'words'] values
    z = []
    z = index.values()[i] 
    try:

        # Because I am interested in follower words
        z = [words[a+1] for a in z]
        print z; print

        # To avoid value errors if a+1 exceeds range of list
    except Exception:
        pass

    # For each word, build r into the dict that contains each follower word and its frequency.

    r = {}
    for key in z:
        r.update({key: counter[key]})

    master.update({index.keys()[i]:r})


return  master
```

Comment: Do you have working code that does this? If so your question may not be suitable for SO, but another site.

Comment: Show us your long code. Counter is the way to go.

Comment: please provide an input that causes a count higher than 1

Comment: If possible for your use case, Consider using a simpler data structure like `{("the", "cat"): 1, ("the", "dog"): 1, ("chased", "the"): 1}`. Then all you need to do is get a [list of consecutive word pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list), and pass it to `Counter`.

Comment: I don't have a choice regarding data structure.  Obviously I am a total newb at Python, sorry for the wall of code.  I really want to be a good member of the SO community and I greatly appreciate any help given!

Comment: Thanks for asking the question! After having to research the `defaultdict` class to understand how it works and how to use it, putting it to working in future programs will probably be far more likely. There is a certain elegance that comes with its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `defaultdict`:

```
import collections

words = ['the', 'cat','chased', 'the', 'dog', 'fled']
result = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for i in range(len(words) - 1):   # loop till second to last word
    occurs = result[words[i]]    # get the dict containing the words that follow and their freqs
    new_freq = occurs.get(words[i+1], 0) + 1  # update the freqs
    occurs[words[i+1]] = new_freq

print list(result.items())
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate it gang.  I am in awe of how quickly yall eviscerated that problem I was grinding against for hours!  I'm working hard to be at that level on day...

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use the `collections` module to implement a working solution:

**Example 1**

```
import itertools
import pprint


def main():
    array = 'the', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog', 'fled'
    frequency = {}
    add_frequency(frequency, array)
    pprint.pprint(frequency)


def add_frequency(frequency, array):
    for a, b in pairwise(array):
        if a in frequency:
            follower = frequency[a]
        else:
            follower = frequency[a] = {}
        if b in follower:
            follower[b] += 1
        else:
            follower[b] = 1


def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s[0], s[1]), (s[1], [s2]), (s[2], s[3]), ..."""
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

The following code shows how you can use `collections.defaultdict` to do as you asked:

**Example 2**

```
import collections
import itertools
import pprint


def main():
    array = 'the', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog', 'fled'
    frequency = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
    add_frequency(frequency, array)
    pprint.pprint(frequency)


def add_frequency(frequency, array):
    for a, b in pairwise(array):
        frequency[a][b] += 1


def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s[0], s[1]), (s[1], [s2]), (s[2], s[3]), ..."""
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

You may also use `functools.partial` instead of a `lambda` when creating the `defaultdict`.

**Example 3**

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
from itertools import tee
from pprint import pprint


def main():
    array = 'the', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog', 'fled'
    frequency = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, int))
    add_frequency(frequency, array)
    pprint(frequency)


def add_frequency(frequency, array):
    for a, b in pairwise(array):
        frequency[a][b] += 1


def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s[0], s[1]), (s[1], [s2]), (s[2], s[3]), ..."""
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple answer, though it does not use defaultdict - just standard dictionary and setdefault.  I may have missed your intent, but this is what I am seeing:

```
def word_analysis(input):
    from itertools import tee, izip
    i1, i2 = tee(input)
    i2.next()
    results = {}
    for w1,w2 in izip(i1,i2):           # Process works pairwise
        d = results.setdefault(w1,{})   # Establish/use the first word dict
        d[w2] = 1 + d.setdefault(w2,0)  # Increment the counter
    return results

print word_analysis(['the', 'cat', 'chased', 'the', 'dog', 'fled'])
```

For me, this offers the same output you reported:

```
{'the': {'dog': 1, 'cat': 1}, 'chased': {'the': 1}, 'dog': {'fled': 1}, 'cat': {'chased': 1}}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: upvoted. I prefer this solution since it avoids using indexes. And it's a great way to teach how to use dictionaries and iterators. Kudos.