# Explode list of lists into separate lists python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

I currently have a list of lists like

```
L = [['E2', 'C1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C2'], ['C1', 'D1', 'A1'], ['C1', 'C2']]
```

My aim is to compare L[i] against L[i+1] to make groups. 
For example, L[2] is a subset of L[0] so I would eliminate it. My two different list will be L[0] and L[1].

For this, if I can somehow explode the list of list into different list, it will be easily achievable by iterating `cmp(L[i], L[i+1])`. By different list I mean, I will store each element as separate variable. => L_1 = L[0], L_2 = L[1] and L_3 = L[2].

zip only seems to do a kind of map between two lists. Can anyone suggest a function available?

Comment: If you somehow stored the sublists as separate variables, you would effectively make it impossible to do what you want (iterate over them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through pairs of items in a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list)

Comment: The lists **are** separate already. Accessing them through a local variable instead of an index makes no difference to what you're trying to do, except perhaps making it harder as the previous comment suggests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could map your list of list to create a list of sets. if you then iterate over that list, it would be possible to check if they are subsets of each other

```python
LSets = map(set, L)

filteredL = filter(lambda s: not any(s.issubset(s2) for s2 in LSets if s != s2), LSets)
```

Comment: Thanks. This creates only set of all elements in listoflists. But, I intend to pickup or retain only L[0] & L[1] and not L[3] as it is already present in L[0].

Comment: @Arun that's what the filter in the second code line is for. It filters out all sets that are a subset aof any of the other sets

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. but If you take a look at the list, all the elements of L[2] is present in L[0] but not all elements of L[1] is present in L[0]. Hence my final output will be L[0] & L[1]. But here the filter creates only L[0] !.

Comment: @Arun When I paste the code from this answer into my python console (2.7.11) filteredL ends up with two sets; L[0] and L[1]. L[1] is not a subset of any of the other, so it is not removed.

Comment: Hi. I too have the same version in mac. But this is the output of filteredL, I get: [set(['A1', 'C2', 'C1', 'B1', 'E2'])] which is L[0]