# Iterate through adjacent pairs in a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I want to access overlapping pairs of adjacent values in a generator.

If it was a list, I could use

```
a = [5, 7, 11, 4, 5]
for v, w in zip(a[:-1], a[1:]):
    print [v, w]
```

Which is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list).

But when I try to do the same with a generator, I get the error

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there a way to do this for generators?

Comment: You cannot apply slicing or indexing to generators. You must coerce them to lists first.

Comment: Is there another way to get overlapping pairs in a generator, without any slicing or indexing?

Comment: Why didn't you use the top answer from the question you linked? That is essentially what I ended up writing.

Comment: I didn't realize the top answer worked for generators. I tried it, it solves my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a generator function to do this:

```
def adjacent_pairs(it):
    it = iter(it)
    a, b = next(it), next(it)
    while True:
        yield a, b
        a, b = b, next(it)
```

Example usage:

```
def gen():
    yield 5
    yield 7
    yield 11
    yield 4
    yield 5
for v, w in adjacent_pairs(gen()):
    print [v, w]
```