# How do I refer to the value of the previous item when using enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I am very simply trying to refer to the value of the previous item when using the enumerate function in Python. I don't know the syntax and cannot find it online. Help much appreciated. Thanks.

```
#if the close price is > line_price, and the previous is < line_price, then increment broken_line_count

mylist = [6000,6000,6000,6200,6200]

line_price = 6100
broken_line_count = 0

for i, x in enumerate(mylist):

    if x>line_price and [i-1](x)<line_price:
        broken_line_count +=1

print(broken_line_count)
```

Obviously `[i-1](x)` is incorrect, this is just illustrative of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You're need `mylist[i-1]`. But a more optimized approach is to use a `zip` function for loop over the pairs so that you can have access to the both items at the same time. In this case you'll refuse of an indexing each time.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list/5764807

Comment: Thanks, that's worked great.Sorry if this is a duplicate, I looked at the link and it doesn't refer to the enumerate function which is what I thought I was struggling with.