# iterating on slices of array in Python, with number of variables

Tags: python-3.x, variables, for-loop, iteration

Let's say I get a list, and I want to iterate on three at a time. I.e.: I have a list with `[1,4,5,6,7,8,-9,2,0]` In TCL, I can just use (for example):

```
foreach { x y z } $list {
   puts "x is ${x}"
   puts "y is ${y}"
   puts "z is ${z}"
}
```

How can I define more than 1 variable, using the for loop with the in (array name) in Python 3.3? The Python org wiki showed just example of 1 iteration variable. This is also easily done in Ruby
Thanks.

**EDIT:** The expected output is:

```
x is 1
y is 4
z is 5
x is 6
y is 7
z is 8
x is -9
y is 2
z is 0
```

Comment: Can you tell what is the expected output of your sample program? What happens if the array length cannot be divided by 3?

Comment: I think this thread could help you, if this is your scenario. Hard to tell without the expected output for your example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list

Comment: You got it right. The assumption is that it is already qualified for the range of 3. It was a general syntax question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether you expect to see `1, 4, 5`, then `6, 7, 8` and then `-9, 2, 0`, OR whether you expect to see `1, 4, 5`, then `4, 5, 6`, then `5, 6, 7` and so on.. I think you should refine your question in order to be able to get a well-explained answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split this array into [chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks), and then just do something like this:

```
for x,y,z in chunked_array:
    print("x=", x)
    print("y=", y)
    print("z=", z)
```