# Chunking list including overlapping intervals

Tags: python, list, chunks

Given the following list:

```
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000]
```

I know I can create chunks of it by looking at every consecutive pair of numbers:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

for group in chunker(l1, 2):
   print(group)
```

This returns:

```
[0, 1000]
[5000, 10000]
[20000, 30000]
[40000, 50000]
```

How can I make sure that overlapping intervals, such as `[1000,5000]`, are also included?

Expected output:

```
[0, 1000]
[1000, 5000] 
[5000, 10000]
[10000, 20000]
[20000, 30000]
[30000, 40000]
[40000, 50000]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Iterate over `zip(l1[:-1], l1[1:])`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through pairs of items in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You unnecessarily iterate over range with the step size. This way you prevent groups starting in place where the other group finishes. This code should work:

```
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000]

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq)))

for group in chunker(l1, 2):
   print(group)
```

The output is:

```
[0, 1000]
[1000, 5000]
[5000, 10000]
[10000, 20000]
[20000, 30000]
[30000, 40000]
[40000, 50000]
[50000]
```

You may skip the last element if that is what you wish, but depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

One way is using a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
[[i,j] for i,j in zip(l1[:-1], l1[1:])]

[[0, 1000],
 [1000, 5000],
 [5000, 10000],
 [10000, 20000],
 [20000, 30000],
 [30000, 40000],
 [40000, 50000]]
```

---

Or using your approach, but setting a step of `1` (which is also the default step size) in the `range`:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), 1))

for group in chunker(l1, 2):
    print(group)

[0, 1000]
[1000, 5000]
[5000, 10000]
[10000, 20000]
[20000, 30000]
[30000, 40000]
[40000, 50000]
[50000]
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
l1 = [0,1000,5000,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000]

def chunker(seq, size):
    return ([seq[i], seq[i+1]] for i in range(len(seq)) if i<len(seq)-1)

for group in chunker(l1, 2):
   print(group)

# result:
[0, 1000]
[1000, 5000]
[5000, 10000]
[10000, 20000]
[20000, 30000]
[30000, 40000]
[40000, 50000]
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi you just have to delete the footstep:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq)))

for group in chunker(l1, 2):
   print(group)


[1000, 5000]
[5000, 10000]
[10000, 20000]
[20000, 30000]
[30000, 40000]
[40000, 50000]
[50000]
```