# Compare all elements of a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

To illustrate my problem, imagine I have a `list` and I want to compare each element with the next one to check if they are the same value. The problem is that when I try to access the last element of the list and compare it with "the next one", that one is out of range, so I would get an error. So, to avoid this, I put a condition when accessing that last element, so I avoid the comparison.

```
list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1,1]

for i in range(len(list)):
    if i == len(list)-1:
        print('Last element. Avoid comparison')
    else:
        if list[i] == list[i+1]:
            print('Repeated')
```

I guess that there should be a more efficient way to do this. For instance, I was trying to set the condition in the definition of the for loop, something like this:

```
for i in range(len(list)) and i < len(list)-1
```

But that is invalid. Any suggestion about how to do this in a more efficient/elegant way?

Comment: I image `for i in range(len(list) - 1)` would solve the problem of trying to access beyond the last element. Then the conditional would become `if list[i] == list[i-1]`

Comment: @SimonCrowe the condition should be the same, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, yes I think `[i+1]` should be fine now. With `[i-1]` Python would compare the first and last element on the first iteration because of how the subscript `[-1]` works in Python.  I _think_ this would still give the desired result, but not be very readable.

Comment: Why not to make it simpler: `all(x == a[0] for x in a)`, this will compare each element with first element in the list and return `True` or `False`. Or `all(a[i] == a[0] for i in range(len(a)))` if you want to deal with indices.

Comment: @adnik I think the question is looking to compare contiguous pairs of values rather than all values in the list.

Comment: Yes, that is, just contiguous pairs. The solution was easy, actually, I tried but I thought I was wrong because `for i in range(len(list) - 1)` the last value of i is `i = len(list) - 2` and I was confused with this. Thank you

Comment: @SimonCrowe, oh, so comparing pairs of neighbouring items. Then, `[a[i] == a[i + 1] for i in range(len(a) - 1)]` would give you list of boolean values: True if items repeat and False otherwise. FYI, DON'T call your variable by KEY WORD, namely `list`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through pairs of items in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to start from 0, you should use:

```
for i in range(len(list) - 1):
    if list[i] == list[i + 1]:
        print('Repeated')
```

The parameter `stop` of [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) function is just integer, so you can use value `len(list) - 1` instead of `len(list)` to stop iterating on last but one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the functionality of `range` as follows:

```
for i in range(1, len(list)):
    if list[i-1] == list[i]:
        print('Repeated')
```

In this way, you won't overrun the list.

Comment: I need to start `i` in 0, as I need to do other operations with the index in 0. Starting in 1 solve the problem, but not for my purpose

Comment: If you need to do certain operations with the 0 index, do them outside the loop by directly dealing with list[0]!!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have solved this, but I think it's worth mentioning an approach that may be closer to idiomatic Python. Python provides iterable unpacking and other tools like the `zip` function to avoid accessing elements of sequences by index.

```py
# Better to avoid shadowing the build-in name `list`
a_list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1]

for value, following_value in zip(a_list, a_list[1:]):
    if value == following_value:
       print("Repeated!")
```

The [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package also has a useful function for this called [pairwise](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise).

Comment: this is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

start from one and look backwards

```
for i in range(1, len(list)): 
    if list[i-1] == list[i]:
        print('Repeated')
```

Comment: I need to start i in 0, as I need to do other operations with the index in 0. Starting in 1 solve the problem, but not for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1]

for i in range(len(list)):    
    if i+1 < len(list) and list[i] == list[i+1]:
        print('Repeated')
```

Answer (score 0):

- len(list) is 8
- range(len(list)) is 0, 1, ..., 7
  but you want the for loop to skip when the index is 6 right?

so given that case ... `if i == len(list)-1:` this condition will be True when the index is 7 (not the index that you want)

Just change that to `if i == len(list)-2:`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  The most common one is to use zip to pair each item with its successor:

```
if any(item == successor for item,successor in zip(lst,lst[1:])):
    print('repeated')
```

`groupby` from itertools is also a popular choice (but not optimal for this):

```
if any(duplicate for _,(_,*duplicate) in itertools.groupby(lst)):
    print('repeated')
```

A for-loop would only need to track the previous value (no need for indexing):

```
prev = object() # non-matching initial value
for x in lst:
    if prev==x:              # compare to previous
       print('repeated')
       break
    prev = x                 # track previous for next iteration
```

Iterators can be interesting when traversing data in parallel (here the elements and their predecessors):

```
predecessor = iter(lst)         # iterate over items from first
for x in lst[1:]:               # iterate from 2nd item
    if x == next(predecessor):  # compare to corresponding predecessor
        print('repeated')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 1,1]

for i in range(len(list)):
    if list[i] in list[i+1:i+2]:
        print('repeated')
```

Comment: this answer creates a new problem.
you must iterate until len(list)-1.
your solution will overflow..

Comment: slicing list beyond its length in *python* doesn't cause any overflow, it returns an empty list

Answer (score 0):

If you use only numbers in your list, you might want to work with `numpy`
for instance:

```
import numpy as np
np_arr = np.array(lst)  # don't use 'list' for your object name. 
diffs = np.diff(np_arr)
diffs_indices = np.where(diffs != 0)[0]
```

It is unclear what your exact uses, but for example in my code, you will get:

```
>>> diffs_indexes
array([0, 1, 3, 4, 5])
```

Which are the indices where elelment[i] != element[i+1]