# How to select 2 elements from a list such that it represents the size of a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I was solving the matrix chain problem and I've encountered a dead end.

I have the values of `p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5` as `4,10,3,12,20,7` respectively

now I want to mark that `p0` and `p1` combine together to form a matrix of `[4][10]` size. Similarly `p1` and `p2` combine to form a matrix of `[10][3]` size.

**please help me in python language**

Comment: You can create a list `p_list = [p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5] = [4,10,3,12,20,7]`, and then [Iterate through pairs of its items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5764782/14627505). Is this what you want?

Comment: Yup, I want with code please.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get?

Comment: separate representation like m1=[4,10], m2=[10,3] ... and so on, this can be done manually but I want it with a code to make it more dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a list of the ps then zip together the `0 to n-1` elements with `1 to n` and list them:

```
p = [4,10,3,12,20,7]
m1, m2, m3, m4, m5  =  list( zip( p[:-1],p[1:] ) )
```

Comment: `p[:-1]` can be just `p` because `zip` automatically stops when the shortest sequence ends

Comment: yup, but for me it's moe clear to explicity take 2 list from same length in `zip`

Answer (score 0):

```py
p_list = [p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5] = [4,10,3,12,20,7]
m_list = []

for a, b in zip(p_list, p_list[1:]):
    m_list.append([a, b])

m1, m2, m3, m4, m5 = m_list
```