# merging sets which have even one element in common

Tags: python, algorithm, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: simple list merging based on intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110837/python-simple-list-merging-based-on-intersections)

I am trying to classify objects. Each object is identified by a unique identifier property called `id`. So my classification logic goes like this. First i prepare a list of objects and then the classification function takes 2 objects at a time and returns a `frozenset` containing their `id`. So if `object1` and `object5` are in the same category a `frozenset(id1,id5)` is returned. Now i keep adding these frozensets to a set so in the end i have a set like this

```
matched_set=(
             frozenset(id1,id2),
             frozenset(id9,id3),
             frozenset(id9,id2),
             frozenset(id24,id22),
             frozenset(id1,id23),
             frozenset(id25,id24),
             frozenset(id30,id24)
            )
```

Now because objects with `id1` and `id2` are in the same category, objects with `id9` and `id3` are in the same category, objects with `id9` and `id2` are in the same category, objects with `id1,id2,id3,id9` should be in same category. So i should have a set like this `set(id1,id2,id3,id9)`
Can someone provide an algorithm to do so?
Thanks

Comment: The linked question contains several viable solutions.

Comment: @DSM Thanks a lot for pointing me to that

Comment: For answers in many languages see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consoldation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [disjoint-set datastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Given your set of id's, your categories separate them into disjoint subsets.  A disjoint-set datastructure represents each category by choosing a representative id, which will be returned by a query of any of its members. (isolated id's form one category apiece, and return themselves)

Updates to a disjoint-set datastructure combine the categories of any two id's, so that future queries return the same representative for members of both subsets.  (if the two id's are already members of the same category, the update is functionally a no-op)

The usual method is to represent each category as a reverse-tree:  each id has a `parent` link, but no child links.  The "representative element" is the root of the tree, which is easy to query by following the parent links.  An update requires finding the root of the trees of both id's, and (if they are different) merging the trees by making one root the parent of the other.

By adding a couple of simple optimizations (queries "collapse" the query path to point directly to the root, and updates always choose the root of the deepest tree as the merge parent), this algorithm  becomes extremely efficient, running in "almost-O(1)" amortized time.

If you want online access to the complete list of id's in each category, you should maintain a cumulative list attached to each category root, and concatenate them in each merge.  In general, it can be convenient to maintain any number of statistics about your categories this way.

Comment: +1 and sorry to destroy your 6666 score :)

Comment: Heh, I share the sentiment 8^)

Comment: Extremely efficient indeed! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12064803/567292 for my implementation which beats the socks off everything else suggested there.