# Organize list of tuples into distinct categories

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose you have input of the following format:

```
data = [(1, 5), (7, 2), (3, 4), (4, 8), (6, 3), (5, 2)]
```

I want to organize these numbers into a separate bucket or list.

If a number from a tuple is found inside another tuple then it means that those numbers should go into the same bucket; otherwise, into a different bucket.
For example, from the above example, the numbers will get distributed into two buckets:
`bucket_a = {1, 5, 2, 7}` because of these tuples:

```
(1, 5)
(5, 2)
(7, 2)
```

and
`bucket_b = {3, 4, 6, 8}` because of these tuples:

```
(3, 4)
(4, 8)
```

Comment: As output, do you want lists of tuples or just the buckets as sets?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/17803919, https://stackoverflow.com/q/9353802, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12063545, https://stackoverflow.com/q/13808774 to name a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a connected components problem where `data` defines the edges of your graph. One way to solve it is using a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Here's an example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> sets = defaultdict(set)
>>> for a in range(1,9): sets[a].add(a)
...
>>> for a,b in data:
...     s = sets[a] | sets[b]
...     for c in s: sets[c] = s
...
>>> sets
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {1: set([1, 2, 5, 7]), 2: set([1, 2, 5, 7]), 3: set([8, 3, 4, 6]), 4: set([8, 3, 4, 6]), 5: set([1, 2, 5, 7]), 6: set([8, 3, 4, 6]), 7: set([1, 2, 5, 7]), 8: set([8, 3, 4, 6])})
```

Note that there are much better disjoint-set implementations than what I've done here, but the idea is the same.

To get a list of unique buckets just get the unique values in `sets` by `id`:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> for s in sets.values():
...     if id(s) not in seen:
...         print s
...         seen.add(id(s))
...
set([1, 2, 5, 7])
set([8, 3, 4, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep track of the buckets and the edges that generated those, this solution uses a `dict` to keep track of both.

```
def get_buckets(data):
    buckets = {}
    for x, y in data:
        if x in buckets and y in buckets:
            if buckets[x] is buckets[y]:
                buckets[x].append((x, y))
            else:
                buckets[x].extend(buckets[y])
                buckets[x].append((x, y))
                for a in sum(buckets[y], ()):
                    buckets[a] = buckets[x]
        elif x in buckets:
            buckets[x].append((x, y))
            buckets[y] = buckets[x]
        elif y in buckets:
            buckets[y].append((x, y))
            buckets[x] = buckets[y]
        else:
            buckets[x] = buckets[y] = [(x, y)]

    return {frozenset(sum(bucket, ())): bucket
            for bucket in map(frozenset, buckets.values())}
```

Example:

```
data = [(1, 5), (7, 2), (3, 4), (4, 8), (6, 3), (5, 2)]
get_buckets(data)
# output:
# {frozenset({1, 2, 5, 7}): frozenset({(1, 5), (5, 2), (7, 2)}),
#  frozenset({8, 3, 4, 6}): frozenset({(6, 3), (3, 4), (4, 8)})}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most optimal, but here is my solution:

```
In [101]: data = [(1, 5), (7, 2), (3, 4), (4, 8), (6, 3), (5, 2)]

In [102]: def merge(data):
     ...:     ndata = len(data)
     ...:     sets = [set(data[0])]
     ...:     for d in data[1:]:
     ...:         found = False
     ...:         for s in sets:
     ...:             if s.intersection(d):
     ...:                 s.update(d)
     ...:                 found = True
     ...:                 break
     ...:         if not found:
     ...:             sets.append(set(d))
     ...:     if len(sets) == ndata:
     ...:         return sets
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return merge(sets)
     ...:     

In [103]: merge(data)
Out[103]: [{1, 2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 6, 8}]
```