# merging list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to group tuples based on similar attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808774/i-want-to-group-tuples-based-on-similar-attributes)

I am very new to Python and coding in general, have a list of cluster pairs like so

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[2,3],[4,5]......],
```

I have written this code to join the cluster pairs into list of larger clusters.

```
for i in range (len(Clist)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(Clist)):
        for disk in Clist[i]:
            if disk in Clist[j]:
                joined=joincluster(Clist[i], Clist[j])
                Clist[i]=list(set(joined))
                Clist[j]=[]
                break
```

I go on to take the empty ones out.
However it doesn't join all the pairs up when i have more then 30 or so cluster pairs, some clusters that should have been joined have not been. I can't see where I'm going wrong? Can anybody me identify the problem?

```
[[0, 2], [0, 9], [1, 10], [2, 0], [2, 9], [3, 6], [3, 10], [3, 11], [4, 5], [4, 7], [4, 12], [4, 14], [5, 4], [5, 8], [5, 12], [5, 14], [6, 3], [6, 10], [6, 11], [7, 4], [7, 12], [8, 5], [8, 14], [9, 0], [9, 2], [9, 13], [10, 1], [10, 3], [10, 6], [10, 11], [11, 3], [11, 6], [11, 10], [12, 4], [12, 5], [12, 7], [13, 9], [14, 4], [14, 5], [14, 8]]
```

Sorry, problem only happens when i have a fairly large number of pairs.
And this is what I get

```
[[0, 9, 2, 13], [11, 1, 10, 3, 6], [3, 6], [4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14]]
```

so the 3,6 there should have been merged but it hasn't.

Comment: Could you add a sample input and output ?

Comment: How exactly do you want to merge them? We need to see some logic behind your input and output, which clusters do you want to merge with which?

Comment: Well i just want to merge the lists, that contain the same numbers, so for example [1,2] gets merged with [2,8] to make [1,2,8]. Im not sure what you mean by where, but the merged lists should be in the same original list that the clusters were in, if its easier, in a completely new list.

Comment: Is this an assignment question ?

Comment: You need to provide more details on what you actually want to achieve. What are the exact rules?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a simpler example, with only 4 clusters like so:

```
clusters = [ [1, 10], [1, 20], [3, 6], [3, 10] ]
```

These 4 are enough to show why `[3, 6]` gets separated from all other clusters. You loop through these clusters starting from first to last. Here's what happens:

1. Is there already a cluster that has `1` or `10` in it? - No, create a new one including both. We now have the following: `[[1, 10]]`.
2. Is there already a cluster that has `1` or `20` in it? - Yes, append to the match. We now have the following: `[[1, 10, 20]]`.
3. Is there already a cluster that has `3` or `6` in it? - No, create a new one including both. We now have the following: `[[1, 10, 20], [3, 6]]`.
4. Is there already a cluster that has `3` or `10` in it? - Yes, append to the match. We now have the following: `[[1, 3, 10, 20], [3, 6]]`.

Problem is: after appending `[3, 10]` to `[1, 10]`, it doesn't check if there are existing clusters that have `3` in them already, which don't have `10`. You need to add that to your code and it will work fine.