# Combine lists that have at least a number in common in a list of lists, Python

Tags: python, list

Consider this list of lists:

```
l = [ [1], [1], [1,2,3], [4,1], [5], [5], [6], [7,8,9], [7,6], [8,5] ]
```

I want to combine all the lists that have at least one number in common, that will be done iteratively until it finished and no dubletters will go with. The result will be:

```
combine(l) = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9] ]
```

is there any neat way to do this, perhaps with itertools?

Comment: But will you add the last list to the first list (5 common) or the second one (8 common)?

Comment: Sorry wrote wrong there..

Comment: you mean `combine(l) = [[1,2,3,4], [5,8], [6,7], [6,7,8,9]]` ?

Comment: Well, I want it do be done iteratively, so the finish result will be as in the example.

Comment: The lists in l can be in any order. The lists of numbers are not ordered.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is known as [set consolidation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation) (or alternatively you can view it as a connected-components problem). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110837/python-simple-list-merging-based-on-intersections) for many implementations.

Answer (score 1):

```
out = []
for l in lists:
    for o in out:
        if set(l).intersection(set(o)):
            o[:] = list(set(l) + set(o))  # Mutate, don't reassign temp var
            break
    else:
        out.append(l)
```

Not perfectly written, could be optimized and is not sorted, but should give you the idea of how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but since `out` starts out empty, I don't see how any of the code under `for o in out` is ever run.

Comment: And further to `if set(l).intersection(set(o)):`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
l = [ [1], [1], [1,2,3], [4,1], [5], [5], [6], [7,8,9], [7,6], [8,5] ]
a, b = [], map(set, l)

while len(a) != len(b):
    a, b = b, []
    for x in a:
        for i, p in enumerate(b):
            if p & x:
                b[i] = p | x
                break
        else:
            b.append(x)        

print a
# [set([1, 2, 3, 4]), set([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Answer (score 0):

My naive attempt:

1. merge all tuples when their intersection is not empty
2. sort each tuple
3. remove duplicate tuples
4. repeat this until there are no more changes.

---

Example:

```
def combine_helper(l):
    l = map(set, l)
    for i, x in enumerate(l, 1):
        x = set(x)
        for y in l[i:]:
            if x & y:
                x = x | y
        yield tuple(sorted(x))

def combine(l):
    last_l = []
    new_l = l
    while last_l != new_l:
        last_l = new_l
        new_l = list(set(combine_helper(last_l)))
    return map(list, last_l)

l = [ [1], [1], [1,2,3], [4,1], [5], [5], [6], [7,8,9], [7,6], [8,5] ]
print combine(l)
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion to the rescue! And don't forget reduce!

```
input_list = [ [1], [1], [1, 2, 3], [4, 1], [5], [5], [6], [7, 8, 9], 
               [7, 6], [8, 5] ]
def combine(input_list):
    input_list = map(set, input_list) # working with sets has some advantages
    reduced_list = reduce(combine_reduce, input_list, [])
    if len(reduced_list) == len(input_list):
        # return the whole thing in the original format (sorted lists)
        return map(sorted, map(list, reduced_list))
    else:
        # recursion happens here
        return combine(reduced_list)

def combine_reduce(reduced_list, numbers):
    '''
    find the set to add the numbers to or append as a new set.
    '''
    for sub_set in reduced_list:
        if sub_set.intersection(numbers):
            sub_set.update(numbers)
            return reduced_list
    reduced_list.append(numbers)
    return reduced_list

print combine(input_list)
```

Prints out:

```
$ python combine.py
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

We have two things going on here. The first is `reduce`: I'm using it to cook the list down, by fitting each element into the resulting list somewhere or appending it, if that didn't work. This does not do the whole job, though, so we repeat this process (recursion!) until reducing does not provide a shorter list.

Also, use of `set` allows for the handy `intersection` method. You will notice the line with `map(set, input_list)` is redundant in recursion. Extracting a wrapper function `combine` from the inner function `combine_inner` and placing the formatting / unformatting (from `list` to `set` and back) in the outer function is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to introduce the following attempt:

1. Make a list of 1-element sets with individual values present in the list. This is the output list.
2. The l list is a recipe how items in the output list should be joined. e.g. If the output list is `[{1}, {2}, {3}]` and the first element in the l list is `[1,3]`, then all sets containing 1 and 3 in the output list should be joined: `output = [{1,3}, {2}]`.
3. Repeat step 2. for every item on the l list.

Code:

```
l = [ [1], [1], [1,2,3], [4,1], [5], [5], [6], [7,8,9], [7,6], [8,5] ]

def compose(l):
    # the following will convert l into a list of 1-element sets:
    # e.g. [ {1}, {2}, ... ]
    r = sum(l, [])
    r = map(lambda x: set([x]), set(r))

    # for every item in l
    # find matching sets in r and join them together
    for item in map(set, l):
        outside = [x for x in r if not x & item]  # elements untouched
        inside = [x for x in r if x & item]       # elements to join
        inside = set([]).union(*inside)           # compose sets 
        r = outside + [inside]
    return r
```

Example:

```
>>> compose(l)
[set([1, 2, 3, 4]), set([8, 9, 5, 6, 7])]
```