# how to merge two sublists sharing any number in common?

Tags: python, list

Given that

> g=[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6],[6,7],[10,11]]

What code should I use to get `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[10,11]]`?

Comment: You should try some code then ask for working code.

Comment: @iCodez: I disagree that's the right duplicate.  If I read the question correctly, the OP is after a consolidation operation, not merely a flattening.

Comment: @DSM - That was not in the original question.  The OP edited since then; he was just doing flattening before.  I'll vote to reopen since this question is no longer a dupe (of the one I picked).

Comment: @NPE: I mean something like [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation), a connected-components problem.  Something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110837/python-simple-list-merging-based-on-intersections).

Comment: @iCodez: "how to merge two sublists sharing any number in common?" was never about flattening, although it could definitely have been clearer.

Comment: Now (post-edit) it looks like a dupe of a much clearer question from the same OP. Go figure. O.o

Comment: Sorry for being confusing but I have just edited the code hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @NPE:

Sorry for being confusing but I have just edited the code hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @iCodez:
Sorry for being confusing but I have just edited the code hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @NaLai: Well, you keep editing the question, but it remains unclear how it's not a duplicate of your question from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

#### This should work:

`list(set(sum(g, [])))`

Output:`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`