# CPU and Memory Friendly Solution to Merge Large Matrix

Tags: matlab, merge, cluster-analysis

For the following typical case:

```
n = 1000000;
r = randi(n,n,2);
```

(assume there are 0.05% common numbers between all rows; `n` could be even tens of millions)

I am looking for a **CPU and Memory efficient solution** to merge rows based on any common items (here integer numbers). A list of sample codes in Python is available **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110837/python-simple-list-merging-based-on-intersections)** and a quick try to translate one into Matlab can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938833/python-merge-function-translated-into-matlab-not-working)**.

In my attempt they take ages (minutes to hours), so I am in favor of finding faster solution.

For the above example, the typical output should look like (cell):

```
{
[1 90 34 67 ... 9]
[35 89]
[45000 23 828 130 8999 45326 ... 11]
...
}
```

Note also that, I have tried to compile as **mex** but failed due to no-support for cell in Matlab-Coder.

**Edit: A tiny demonstration example**

```
%---------------------------------------
clc
n = 100;
r = randi(n,n,2);        % random integers in [1,n], size(n,2)
%---------------------------------------
>> r
r =
    82    17             % (1) 82 17
    91    13             % (2) 91 13
    13    32             % (3) 91 13 32            merged with (2), common 13
    82    53             % (4) 82 17 53            merged with (1), common 82
    64    17             % (5) 82 17 53 64         merged with (4), common 17
    ...
    94    45
    13    31             % (77) 91 13 32 31        merged with (3), common 13
    57    51
    47    52
     2    13             % (80) 91 13 32 31 2      merged with (77), common 13
    34    80
%---------------------------------------
c = merge(r);            % cpu and memory friendly solution is searched for.
%---------------------------------------
c =
    [82 17 53 64]
    [91 13 32 31 2]
    ...
```

Comment: You need to define what "merge" means here. Or give the exact input that produces that example output

Comment: @LuisMendo In the newly added demonstration, for the given data the product is shown. So the question becomes much clear. Pay attention to the comments in the demonstration code.

Comment: I see. Interesting question, but tricky

Comment: You're searching for connected components in an undirected graph. If you have 2015b or later, you can try [graph.conncomp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.conncomp.html), but I don't know how fast it is.

Comment: @beaker I see, unfortunately it is a lower version of Matlab and it seems there is no `graph` toolbox or `conncomp` function available to me. It therefore would be great if someone could contribute to answer with a pure Matlab implementation of `conncomp` so no need for any other third party or other licenses.

Comment: @Developer Fortunately, you can do this with a simple BFS. You can find several implementations on File Exchange or write your own. I'll try to have a look when I get a bit more time.

Comment: Here are a couple of approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883367/how-to-find-connected-components-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

You need an index.

In Python, use a dict. In MATLAB - I'd not use MATLAB, because open-source is the future, and MATLAB is dying out.

But Python is quite slow. You can likely get a 10x speedup by using e.g. Cython to translate and optimize the code in C. Avoid using Python data types such as a `list` of `int`, because they are very memory intensive. numpy has memory-efficient arrays of integer.

If you get a new pair (a,b) you can use this dictionary to find existing items to merge. Then update the dict after the merge.
Actually for integers, you should use an array instead of a dict.

The trickiest part is handling the case when both a and b exist, but are large different groups. There are some neat optimizations possible here, if that isn't fast enough yet.

It's not clustering, but connected components.

Comment: You're probably correct about the open source part. However, this is a question asking for hints or guidance or experience in implementing a solution for the described question in Matlab. I am curious to see a pure Matlab or Python (so I can translate it into Matlab) implementation of connected components.

Comment: I probably have to dig in through `scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components` to see if there is simple implementation out there.

Comment: Simple tends to contradict "CPU and Memory efficient".