# Python merge multiple list with intersection

Tags: python, list, intersection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: simple list merging based on intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110837/python-simple-list-merging-based-on-intersections)

I have a multiple list:

```
 list=[[1,2,3],[3,5,6],[8,9,10],[11,12,13]]
```

Is there a smart and fast way to get all the sublists with at least one intersection. In my example I want that the code return

```
 result=[[1,2,3,5,6],[8,9,10],[11,12,13]]
```

Comment: As the other question didn't have a good answer, I don't think this should be closed yet!

Comment: @katrielalex: On what basis are you saying that? "A better data structure could be of help", yes I agree on that, and you're free to add your solution too.

Comment: @Rik: looking through the comments, it seemed that all the answers were not-working in one way or another. I only read them briefly though!

Comment: @katrielalex: That's because we all encountered the same bug Sven Marnach seems to have. But we also **fixed that**, that's why there are a lot of comments. Basically the problem is that you may have two or more lists "linked" by a non-common element from another list.

Comment: @RikPoggi -- so you have. I can't retract the bounty; I'll pick which answer to award it to in a week!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but maybe isn't very elegant:

```
def merge_lists(l):
        s=map(set, l)
        i, n=0, len(s)
        while i < n-1:
                for j in xrange(i+1, n):
                        if s[i].intersection(s[j]):
                                s[i].update(s[j])
                                del s[j]
                                n-=1
                                break
                else:
                        i+=1
        return [sorted(i) for i in s]
```

Comment: Test your code with this data: `[[65, 17, 5, 30, 79, 56, 48, 62], [6, 97, 32, 93, 55, 14, 70, 32], [75, 37, 83, 34, 9, 19, 14, 64], [43, 71], [], [89, 49, 1, 30, 28, 3, 63], [35, 21, 68, 94, 57, 94, 9, 3], [16], [29, 9, 97, 43], [17, 63, 24]]` and check it against one of the solution in the duplicate question. The result should not be the same. This problem was already encountered there when the merging is not trivial.

Comment: Ok fixed. Not that it matters since the thread was closed anyways ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with essentially a single pass through the data:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 6], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13]]
sets = {}
for lst in list_of_lists:
    s = set(lst)
    t = set()
    for x in s:
        if x in sets:
            t.update(sets[x])
        else:
            sets[x] = s
    for y in t:
        sets[y] = s
    s.update(t)
ids = set()
for s in sets.itervalues():
    if id(s) not in ids:
        ids.add(id(s))
        print s
```

This creates a dictionary `sets` mapping each element to the set it belongs to.  If some element has been seen before, its set is subsumed into the current one and all dictinary entries mapping to the former set are updated.

Finally we need to find all unique sets in the values of the dictionary `sets`.  Note that while I implemented this  as a dictionary of sets, the code also works with lists instead of sets.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by the `id`s hack -- are you sure it works in all cases? (I haven't quite grokked your algorithm yet.)

Comment: You can do the same thing (but slower, probably) with `set(map(frozenset, sets.itervalues()))`.

Comment: Test your code with this data: `[[65, 17, 5, 30, 79, 56, 48, 62], [6, 97, 32, 93, 55, 14, 70, 32], [75, 37, 83, 34, 9, 19, 14, 64], [43, 71], [], [89, 49, 1, 30, 28, 3, 63], [35, 21, 68, 94, 57, 94, 9, 3], [16], [29, 9, 97, 43], [17, 63, 24]]` and check it against one of the solution in the duplicate question. The result should not be the same. This problem was already encountered there when the merging is not trivial.

Comment: @katrielalex: I don't see any problem with `id()` here, though I also thought about a different solution.  Your suggestion would create a set of its own for every element, though, and compares them element-wise when inserting them into the set.  Printing the result would be much slower than computing it...

Comment: @SvenMarnach: yep, true. It just feels... icky. If you see what I mean.

Comment: @RikPoggi: I couldn't find any fundamental problem with my code.  Your data contains a list wich contains `94` twice -- that was not covered by the answer, nor did it seem to be required by the question. (I made the trivial change to include that case.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Seeing that it didn't work on that data test I assumed it was for the same reason, *my apologies*.

Comment: That's actually many orders of magnitude slower than all the other approaches so far. The reason for that is although you save an additional pass through the data, you introduce a lot of overhead for managing the dictionaries and building up the final result.

Comment: @NiklasB.: The code didn't receive any review, and there are a few things that can trivially be improved.  I didn't bother to do so because there were enough good answers, and this question has been closed anyway.  Claiming that my implementation is "many [orders of magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) slower than all the other approaches" is bold, though. I [timed it against your implementation](https://gist.github.com/1879733) on some random data and found that the difference is less than a factor of two.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Really? I timed it too and the difference were actually more than 2 orders of magnitude (x100 to x1000 and even more on even larger input). Agreed though that this is not relevant any longer.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Just run the code.  The first number it prints is the time in seconds my implementation took, the second number is yours.  A few simple micro-optimisations brought the factor down to 1.25 for me.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: That other benchmark uses a lot more lists. If you want, I can integrate this solution with optimizations. If not, no problem at all :)

Comment: @NiklasB.: I don't really understand what you are suggesting.  Which benchmark is "that other benchmark"?  And are you suggesting to improve my code?  If yes, feel free to do so!  (BTW, when taking only the first half of the test data, my implementation is quite a bit faster than yours and hochl's.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Sorry, I was talking about [my benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9112588/916657) to that duplicate question, always getting confused here. With 5000 lists (5 classes), your function is about 500x slower than Rik's solution over there. Together with your observation that it performs better with less lists, this makes me wonder if it actually is `O(n^2)` rather than `O(n)`. Why would that be? Don't bother to answer if you don't have the time for this.

Comment: @NiklasB.: The complexities of these algortihms cannot be easily described as `O(n)` etc, because it is quite unclear what `n` is. After thinking about it for a bit, I found that all implementation can show some kind of "quadratic" behaviour - mine when there are many sets that get joined in only a few classes, the other solutions if there are many sets that don't get joined.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Yeah, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Since you have a benchmark, how does my solution fare in comparison? Just out of interest.

Comment: @hochl: I didn't do extensive tests.  Basically your code belongs to the group of implementations that get slow if there are many classes in the final solution.  We would need a proper [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to implement this efficiently in all cases.  Both Niklas' and my benchmark are linked above -- it will be really easy to do your own tests if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question! It's much simpler if you think of it as a connected-components problem in a graph. The following code uses the excellent [`networkx`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) graph library and the `pairs` function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257413/iterate-over-pairs-in-a-list-circular-fashion-in-python).

```
def pairs(lst):
    i = iter(lst)
    first = prev = item = i.next()
    for item in i:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
    yield item, first

lists = [[1,2,3],[3,5,6],[8,9,10],[11,12,13]]

import networkx
g = networkx.Graph()
for sub_list in lists:
    for edge in pairs(sub_list):
            g.add_edge(*edge)

networkx.connected_components(g)
[[1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13]]
```

---

### Explanation

We create a new (empty) graph `g`. For each sub-list in `lists`, consider its elements as nodes of the graph and add an edge between them. (Since we only care about connectedness, we don't need to add *all* the edges -- only adjacent ones!) Note that `add_edge` takes two objects, treats them as nodes (and adds them if they aren't already there), and adds an edge between them.

Then, we just find the connected components of the graph -- a solved problem! -- and output them as our intersecting sets.

Comment: I would suggest moving your answer to the other question.

Comment: I tested your answer with this data: `[[65, 17, 5, 30, 79, 56, 48, 62], [6, 97, 32, 93, 55, 14, 70, 32], [75, 37, 83, 34, 9, 19, 14, 64], [43, 71], [], [89, 49, 1, 30, 28, 3, 63], [35, 21, 68, 94, 57, 94, 9, 3], [16], [29, 9, 97, 43], [17, 63, 24]]` and your result seems to be missing a `16`.

Comment: @Rik: nice point -- there was a bug in the `pairs` function I copied from the linked question! =p Fixed.