# For loop syntax in Python without using range() or xrange()

Tags: python, syntax

I do not know much about python so i apologize if my question is a very basic one.

Let's say i have a list

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Now what i want to know is that if there is any way to write the following piece of code in python without using `range()` or `xrange()`:

```
for i in lst:
    for j in lst after element i: '''This is the line i want the syntax for'''
        #Do Something
```

The second loop is to access elements after the element `i` i.e., if i = 3, `j` would have to loop through from 4 to 10, so the pairs of numbers if `i` and `j` are printed would be (1,2)..(1,10), (2,3)...(2,10), (3,4)..(3,10) etc.

I have no idea what to search for or what query to type on any search engine.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over pairs in a list (circular fashion) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257413/iterate-over-pairs-in-a-list-circular-fashion-in-python). Do you want to iterate with the indices `(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)` or `(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)`?

Comment: Also is there a particular reason you don't want to use `range`? Is it for the sake of challenge/curiosity or something else?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan It was just out of curiosity nothing more.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan No i want to iterate with (0,1)...(0,10), then (1,2)...(1,10), then (2,3)..(2,10), this sort of looping.

Comment: Ah, apologies. The link may be helpful but it's not a duplicate then.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Not a problem. It's always better to have more knowledge :) Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what list slicing is about, you can take part of your list from i'th element through

```
lst[i:]
```

furthermore, in order to have both index and value you need `enumerate` operation, which changes the list into list of pairs `(index, value)`

thus

```
for ind, i in enumerate(lst):
    for j in lst[ind+1: ]: 
        #Do Something
```

Comment: Thank you list slicing is the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you might want to use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    for j in lst[index+1:]:
        #Do Something
```

Comment: lst[index+1] is not a list, it is an element, furthermore, enumerate does not work this way around

Comment: Also, I get the order of index and item in `enumerate` wrong every time I try to use it. It's like trying to get a USB in on the first try...

Comment: @turbulencetoo does that also mean that sometimes you get the order right but it still doesn't work so you reflexively try the other way?

Comment: I learned something new from your answer. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

can't we do it like simply:

```py
for i in range(len(lst)):  
     for j in lst[i+1:]:  
        #Do Something
```